# How can I assert throws in Junit5 without jupiter

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, junit5

I have test in Junit 5 and coverage reports in JaCoCo but when I use in test, a org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions import then i haven't this test on coverage report. Is another way to assert throws?

Answer (score 0):

I found older method like this

@Test(expected = CustomException::class)
fun test (){...}

and it's work fine

Answer (score 0):

org.assertj

```
assertThatThrownBy(() -> myMethodThrowingException())
    .isInstanceOf(MyException.class)
    .hasMessage("exception message");
```